Standard Logicapp EDI X12Encode X12MessageEncodingFailed Error
We have upgraded to a standard logic app from the consumption version.  The consumption version used to tell us when we had invalid EDI, which segment specifically had the problem.
The standard version is now giving a generic error message like
X12MessageEncodingFailed
An error occurred while encoding the X12 message. Error code: 'InvalidDataElementsInSegment'. Error description: 'Segment has data element errors.'
Does anyone know of any way to find out which segment has the error?
-Randy

Yes, in Consumption plan, the connector will give segment error in detailed way, where as in Standard Logic app, the connectors do not give detailed error message , rather gives a generic error.
Design:

Output:
When given wrong details, it says bad request.

Whereas in Consumption Plan you will get clear error message:

This is how standard Plan is, so one cannot change the internal design of connector in a particular plan

Crazy.  1 step forward 2 steps back.  Thanks for the confirmation.  I'll implement some work around.
